# Google Analytics iOS SDK [GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged: crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I keep on experiencing crash in my iOS app that is related to the GAIReachabilityChecker.

It seems to crash on this function:
**-[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:]**

**And this is the error log:**

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread

```
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001981939d0 objc_msgSend + 16
1                                 0x0000000100274de8 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:]
2  SystemConfiguration            0x000000018f0905cc reachPerform + 836
3  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018c1db77c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018c1daad8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 256
5  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018c1d8d70 __CFRunLoopRun + 632
6  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018c119b38 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
7  GraphicsServices               0x0000000191b3f830 GSEventRunModal + 168
8  UIKit                          0x000000018f1580e8 UIApplicationMain + 1156
9                                 0x0000000100072870 main (main.m:17)
10 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000198783aa0 start + 4
```

There are no steps reproduce this issue, it just randomly crashing.

I'm using the the latest Google Analytics iOS SDK version   3.0