# Random crashes on iOS App Google Tag Manager implementation

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, google-tag-manager

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

I'm implementing Google Tag Manager in an iOS App. 99% works well, but some times App crashes with the following execptions in:

-[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:]

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3426bae6 objc_msgSend + 5
1  SuppApp                        0x001d3c11 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] + 2481169
2  SystemConfiguration            0x26b1544d reachPerformAndUnlock + 256
3  CoreFoundation                 0x22a0a827 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
4  CoreFoundation                 0x22a0a417 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 454
5  CoreFoundation                 0x22a0877f __CFRunLoopRun + 806
6  CoreFoundation                 0x2295b1e9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
7  CoreFoundation                 0x2295afdd CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
8  GraphicsServices               0x2ba76af9 GSEventRunModal + 160
9  UIKit                          0x26bc017d UIApplicationMain + 144
10 SuppApp                        0x00061cef main (main.m:16)
11 libdyld.dylib                  0x34989873 start + 2
```

-[GAIDefaultLogger info:]

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x34e8bac6 objc_msgSend + 5
1  SuppApp                        0x0020fb3d -[GAIDefaultLogger info:] + 2149181
2  SuppApp                        0x00219c11 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] + 2190353
3  SystemConfiguration            0x27715431 reachPerformAndUnlock + 256
4  CoreFoundation                 0x23658c3f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2365882d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 452
6  CoreFoundation                 0x23656b9b __CFRunLoopRun + 794
7  CoreFoundation                 0x235aa249 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
8  CoreFoundation                 0x235aa035 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
9  GraphicsServices               0x2c661ad1 GSEventRunModal + 160
10 UIKit                          0x277bf899 UIApplicationMain + 144
11 SuppApp                        0x000a7cef main (main.m:16)
12 libdyld.dylib                  0x355ca873 start + 2
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It is not your fault. This crash caused by google analytics library. And seems like not only you got these crashes:
https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=578

Comment: Here on SO as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187602/google-analytics-ios-sdk-gaireachabilitychecker-reachabilityflagschanged-crash from Jan2015.